# Doxygen only detecting the int main() function

Tags: c, doxygen

I want to document a void function, but doxygen doesnt recognize it. It only recognizes the int main() function. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Please check the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>



/**
 * @file main.c
 * @author Reymi Chacon Soto 
 * @date 3 de octubre 2017 
 * @brief El main file del ejercicio 3
 * 
 * \mainpage Descripcion 
 * Programa para encontrar la solucion de una ecuacion cuadratica. EL usuario ingresa las constantes de la ecuacion
 * 
 * \section libreria_sec Librerias usadas en este proyecto
 * \subsection libreria1 Math.h
 * Esta libreria permite usar la funcion sqrt(); para obtener raiz cuadrada
 */



int main(){

    printf("Se va a trabajar con la ecuacion de la forma ax^2+bx+c\n\n" );



    float a,b,c,x_1,x_2,x_0;

    printf("Ingrese el valor de la constante a: ");
    scanf("%f", &a);

    printf("Ingrese el valor de la constante b: ");
    scanf("%f", &b);

    printf("Ingrese el valor de la constante c: ");
    scanf("%f", &c);



void cuadratica(a,b,c){

/**
 * @brief Funcion que se encarga de encontrar las soluciones de una ecuacion cuadratica segun los parametros
 * ingresados por el usuario.
 * @param a,b,c Constantes de la ecuacion cuadratica
 */    

    double dis = b*b-4*a*c; 

    double sqr = sqrt(dis);


    if(dis<0){

        printf("No tiene solucion en los numeros reales\n");


    }



    if(dis==0){

        x_0= -b/(2*a);

        printf("La solucion es %f\n", x_0);


    }

    if(dis>0){

       x_1= (-b + sqr)/(2*a); 
       x_2= (-b - sqr)/(2*a); 

       printf("Las soluciones son %f y %f\n", x_1, x_2);

    }

}

cuadratica(a,b,c);

}
```

Comment: Did you try writing your comments before `void cuadraica(a,b,c){`? And not after.

Comment: Yes. And it didnt work. So I put inside. No result.

Comment: I think there is something wrong in your code. You declare a function in the `main()` function ?

Comment: Functions don't nest.

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare a function inside a function. This is not OOP, each function as to be one and only one function.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void cuadratica(a,b,c);


/**
 * @file main.c
 * @author Reymi Chacon Soto 
 * @date 3 de octubre 2017 
 * @brief El main file del ejercicio 3
 * 
 * \mainpage Descripcion 
 * Programa para encontrar la solucion de una ecuacion cuadratica. EL usuario ingresa las constantes de la ecuacion
 * 
 * \section libreria_sec Librerias usadas en este proyecto
 * \subsection libreria1 Math.h
 * Esta libreria permite usar la funcion sqrt(); para obtener raiz cuadrada
 */



int main(void){

    printf("Se va a trabajar con la ecuacion de la forma ax^2+bx+c\n\n" );



    float a,b,c,x_1,x_2,x_0;

    printf("Ingrese el valor de la constante a: ");
    scanf("%f", &a);

    printf("Ingrese el valor de la constante b: ");
    scanf("%f", &b);

    printf("Ingrese el valor de la constante c: ");
    scanf("%f", &c);

    cuadratica(a,b,c);
    return (0);
}

void cuadratica(a,b,c){

/**
 * @brief Funcion que se encarga de encontrar las soluciones de una ecuacion cuadratica segun los parametros
 * ingresados por el usuario.
 * @param a,b,c Constantes de la ecuacion cuadratica
 */    

    double dis = b*b-4*a*c; 

    double sqr = sqrt(dis);


    if(dis<0){

        printf("No tiene solucion en los numeros reales\n");


    }



    if(dis==0){

        x_0= -b/(2*a);

        printf("La solucion es %f\n", x_0);


    }

    if(dis>0){

       x_1= (-b + sqr)/(2*a); 
       x_2= (-b - sqr)/(2*a); 

       printf("Las soluciones son %f y %f\n", x_1, x_2);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, you can't declare a function in another function.

Try to declare your function **separately**:

```
void cuadratica(a,b,c){
    // Your method
}

int main(){

    printf("Se va a trabajar con la ecuacion de la forma ax^2+bx+c\n\n" );

    float a,b,c,x_1,x_2,x_0;

    printf("Ingrese el valor de la constante a: ");
    scanf("%f", &a);

    printf("Ingrese el valor de la constante b: ");
    scanf("%f", &b);

    printf("Ingrese el valor de la constante c: ");
    scanf("%f", &c);

    cuadratica(a,b,c);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to put `cuadratica()` function under `main()` in your file, you have to declare it before as:

```
void cuadratica(float, float, float);

int main(){
   // Method
}

void cuadratica(a, b, c){
   // Method
}
```